# Error: Could not establish data connection: Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, docker, vsftpd, port, vsftp

Hi every i used a vsftpd server so this is my configuration and the error output when i test my ftp server online :

```
rsa_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/2m-partners.tn/fullchain.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/2m-partners.tn/privkey.pem
#ssl_enable=NO
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=31000
pasv_address=51.91.250.89
port_enable=YES
ssl_enable=yes
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list
userlist_deny=NO
```

The site is https://ftptest.net/#result and the output error is :

```
Error: Could not establish data connection: Connection refused
Check that is part of your passive mode port range.
If it is outside your desired port range, you have a router and/or firewall that is modifying your FTP data.
Make sure that this port is open in your firewall port needs to be forwarded in your router.
In some cases your ISP might block that port. In this case configure the server to use a different passive mode port range. Contact your ISP for details which ports are blocked.
```

Comment: "Connection refused" can mean many things. Have you followed the suggestions in the error message? You tag your question with "Docker". Why?

Comment: yes i'm using  30000 and 31000  i add it with iptables ! when i tap the command iptables -nL i see that the ports are open but vsftp is not listenenig only in 21 port ! it's mean that the ports 30000 and 31000 are opens ???

Comment: So, vsftpd listens on port 21, and you opened ports 30000 to 31000 in the firewall. Could it be that the firewall blocks port 21?

Comment: no port 21 is always open and ftp is listen on port 21

Comment: The FTP command port is 21, but the default data port is 20.

Comment: i don't know what to do :/